# Using functional and siunitx packages together

Tags: siunitx, functional

I'm trying to use the *functional* package for doing calculations (`\fpAdd`) and then use the *siunitx* package to format the results (`\num`).

Here is a very small example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{functional}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\fpNew \Total
\fpAdd \Total {5.5}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\begin{document}
My number: \fpUse \Total. % This works.
%My number: \num{\fpUse \Total}. % This does not work.
\end{document}
```

Uncommenting the last line gives the following error.

```
! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '\fpUse \s__fp \__fp_chk:w
(siunitx) 10{1}{5500}{0000}{0000}{0000};'.
```

Does anyone know how to do that properly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The commands from the functional package are not expandable. Why don't you use the inbuilt latex command \fpeval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands in `functional` aren't expandable since they go against the TeX language, trying to make it into something different.

Macro expansion goes “from outside to inside”, whereas `functional` wants to achieve the reverse strategy, so it has to avoid macro expansion. Not a judgment, just a description.

However, `\num` wants to fully expand its main argument in order to have an explicit number to manipulate and `functional` commands can't work.

If you just need to manipulate floating point variables, define your own equivalents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newfp}{mo}
 {
  \fp_new:c { l_francesco_var_#1_fp }
  \IfValueT { #2 }
   {
    \fp_set:cn { l_francesco_var_#1_fp } { #2 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfp}{mm}
 {
  \fp_set:cn { l_francesco_var_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addfp}{mm}
 {
  \fp_add:cn { l_francesco_var_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefp}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_francesco_var_#1_fp }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newfp{Total}[5.5]
\newfp{Weird}
\setfp{Weird}{pi^2-exp(3)}

\begin{document}

My number: \usefp{Total}.

My number: \num[output-decimal-marker={,}]{\usefp{Total}}.

My number: \num{\usefp{Weird}}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the advantage over `\fpNew\Total`: you don't need to care whether `\Total` is defined, because `\newfp{Total}` defines a control sequence that's unlikely to be already used for a different purpose.

You also don't have to worry about spaces: compare

```
\fpUse\Total\ is a nice number

\usefp{Total} is a nice number
```